# What does "pullout" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english

I don't understand the meaning of the word *pullout* in this sentence:

> There was a **pullout** on the road leading up to the vehicle parking lot where buses had to turn around because the rest of the climb was too steep. She turned into one of the few parking spaces by a public restroom.

The woman here is driving in the Death Valley National Park, headed for Dante's View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means a small road that is an offshoot of the main road, i.e. it creates a fork, and most people stay on the main road, but those wanting to head to the parking lot would use the pullout.

In other contexts it can mean an area on the side of a mountain road where sightseers can pull over to take pictures without having to use a formal parking space, then continue on the mountain road in the same direction.

[Pullout:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pullout)

> an area at the side of a road where drivers may pull off for emergencies, to rest or view the scenery, etc.; pull-off.

(Dictionary.com)

[Here is an example](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/_AGPFq30aqYY/TIVZdOFjiHI/AAAAAAAAJ8c/g1FOsoHWhKA/s1600/5-clear+day+on+mt+evans.jpg) - the motorcycles are in the pullout.